# Why SignalR Client Methods are not firing everytime?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am writing an ASP.NET Web Form Application with a chat form using SignalR and Jquery.
The Hub Has Methods like,

```
public void SendMessage(string empid, string empName, string message, string time)
    {
        
        Clients.All.messageBroadcasted(empid, userName, message, time);

    }
```

and in the javascript file,

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSendMsg', function () {
var hub = $.connection.myChat;
var msg = $("#txtMessage").val();
if (msg.length > 0) {
    var empid = "1";
    var empname = "user1";
    var date = new Date();
    hub.server.sendMessage(empid, empname, msg, date);
    $("#txtMessage").val('');
}  })
```

and the client method,

```
myHub.client.messageBroadcasted = function (empid, empName, message, time) { 
   
    AppendMessage(empid, empName, message, time);
}
```

Now, the problem is the the client method `myHub.client.messageBroadcasted` is not firing everytime.
Sometimes `AppendMessage` happens, sometimes not. But the hub class is being hit everytime.

Any help would be very appreciated.

**EDIT:** I solved it by registering events before starting the hub!

Comment: this is worked for me 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/78d182/signalr-sample-chat-application-in-C-Sharp/
follow this steps i hope u will get u r correction.